# Creating a dictionary which contains English words

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I want a text file which contains commonly occuring English words but abbreviations or acronyms should not be present there. Is it possible to get that dictionary?
Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this just from `nltk` package

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Comment: This set will contain only the stopwords, but I just want to remove the abbreviations and acronyms from the English dictionary, For example:- 'cd', 'id' should not be present.

Comment: @Ayan Banerjee "**noun: id; plural noun: ids
the part of the mind in which innate instinctive impulses and primary processes are manifest.**" - Google dictionary. Wether or not a word is an abbreviation can depend on context

Comment: @AyanBanerjee as said by Hymns For Disco, it is impossible to remove abbreviations and acronyms as they depend indeed on the context and jargon used (in medical jargon you will have other abbreviations than in legal jargon), the only thing you can do is try to search for them manually with regex, knowing that short words, or with dots (for example "i.e.") or with only consonants should be abbreviations, but won't be perfect !